# how to change <td> title by index number in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm going to use the following script to change the title of the table cells to my liking, but I don't know how to use the index.

```js
$(".week td.enable").click(function () {
   var index = $(this).index();
   var selectCell = $(this);
   selectCell.attr('title', 'X');
 });
```

This code changes all the cells in the table equally!!
When i use selectCell.eq(index).attr('title', 'X');
My code does not apply to cell titles!!

Comment: you should add your table structure to reproduce your code

Comment: You need change title or change cell content? If oyur need change content, use `selectCell.text('X')`

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to change  title by index number:

The first approach:

Numbers starts at 1.

```
$(".week tr td.enable:nth-child(1)").click(function () {
            var selectCell = $(this);
                selectCell.attr('title', 'X');
        });
```

The second approach:

Numbers starts at 0.

```
$(".week tr td.enable").click(function () {
            var selectCell = $(this);
            if (selectCell.index() == "0") {
                selectCell.attr('title', 'X');
            }
        });
```